# how to filter a date in views using a variable?

Tags: sql, view

this query right here is good..

```
 SELECT M.id, 
       M.accnt, 
       amount = M.amount + Isnull(s.supply, 0), 
       issued = Isnull(I.issued, 0) 
FROM   maintbl M 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT id, 
                               Sum(supply) AS supply 
                        FROM   supplytbl 
                        WHERE  Month(dates) = 1  -- Month filter for Jan - feb Month(dates) in (1,2)
                        GROUP  BY id) S 
                    ON s.id = M.id 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT id, 
                               Sum(issued) AS issued 
                        FROM   issuedtbl 
                        WHERE  Month(dateissue) = 1 -- Month filter
                        GROUP  BY id) I 
                    ON I.id = M.id
```

but how can i do this in views ?...filter the date using variables ? like

```
WHERE  Month(dateissue) = textbox1.text
```

or is there any way to query like this in a view ? glad for any help.. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server, you can't pass parameter to view

So, you need to create stored procedure like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testSP
(
    @issue_month INT
) 
AS 
BEGIN
   ...
END
```

Answer (score 1):

stored procedure is the best way to answer your question.

Here's the code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_sample @Month_date_issue int
AS
SELECT M.id, 
       M.accnt, 
       amount = M.amount + Isnull(s.supply, 0), 
       issued = Isnull(I.issued, 0) 
FROM   maintbl M 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT id, 
                               Sum(supply) AS supply 
                        FROM   supplytbl 
                        WHERE  Month(dates) = 1  -- Month filter for Jan - feb Month(dates) in (1,2)
                        GROUP  BY id) S 
                    ON s.id = M.id 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT id, 
                               Sum(issued) AS issued 
                        FROM   issuedtbl 
                        WHERE  Month(dateissue) = @Month_date_issue -- Month filter
                        GROUP  BY id) I 
                    ON I.id = M.id 
GO
```

Here's to call the stored procedure

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_sample", con)) {
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

      cmd.Parameters.Add("@Month_date_issue ", SqlDbType.Int32).Value = Int32.Parse(textbox1.text);

      con.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: aah..so i just have to learn this stored procedure overnight..aaahh..hmmm..btw..tnx mate :)

Comment: i believe you will get used to stored procedure in a blink mate. you're welcome :). See my edited post for how to call the stored procedure with the parameters

Comment: i'll try that out mate..tnx :) 

HAPPY NEW YEAR ! :)

Comment: hmmm..can we use stored proc for crystal report ?

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE monthsearch
@date datetime2
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM <queryname> WHERE <field date>=@date    
END;
```

to call it :
    EXEC monthsearch datetime